# Windows 7 + IPSec: Force all remote traffic through VPN

Tags: networking, windows-7, routing, ipsec, route

I have set up a VPN connection to an remote L2TP/IPSec VPN server, which works fine.
Now i like to ensure that all remote traffic is being routed through this VPN, so if the VPN connection drops, no remote connection is being established

I thought of adding an persistent route, but i'm not sure about the correct syntax and configuration/metric.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: This is tough to do with routing because you have to specify a next hop IP in your route which is going to change with different networks. You'd have to point a route for your VPN endpoint out the physical interface so your VPN doesn't try to route into itself.

Comment: thx for pointing this out. are there any other options available?

Comment: Your best bet is to use a firewall to only allow VPN traffic to exit the physical interface. UDP 500 and protocol 50 or TCP/443 to only your VPN device depending on what kind of VPN you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resmon6 suggestion

> Your best bet is to use a firewall to only allow VPN traffic to exit the physical interface. UDP 500 and protocol 50 or TCP/443 to only your VPN device depending on what kind of VPN you're using.

obviously works in my case. Thanks.